# django 1.7 & delete postgres db & recreate it

Tags: python, django, postgresql

This is such a noob question, but I have an issue with my test database.

I asked the question about a database error I have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007593/django-python-relation-does-not-exist/33007699#33007699).

I now think that if I drop the database and then re-create it, the issue that I have will be resolved.

I am running python 2.7, django 1.7 & postgressql 9.4.

**How do I 'delete' the database and then recreate it?**

I am unsure if I should drop the entire database from the pgAdmin console and then run migrations. I am unsure because if I do this and it it incorrect, I am not sure what to do next to recover.

I have done a data dump. I have all my migrations in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Django by itself does not include what you want.

There are two commands you can use:

```
python manage.py help flush
```

This one will destroy all of the data in your database, but will not delete it.

To delete your database you need to run:

```
python manage.py sqlclear <app>
```

This command will print to the standard output the sql needed to drop the tables on an specific app, but it will not execute it.

If you really want to delete the database and create it again you can use [django_extensions's reset_db](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_extensions.html?highlight=reset_db)
 command, which will destroy your database and create it again.

To install django_extensions (assuming you installed pip), just run:

pip install django_extensions

Then add django_extensions to your `INSTALLED_APPS` variable in settings.py.

After that feel free to run:

```
python manage.py reset_db
```

Hope it helps and create [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/#where-django-finds-fixture-files) to provide initial data for your models...

Comment: averent, thank you. I used `python manage.py reset_db` to delete all the data and the tables - which helped a great deal.